# KDE loads to a blank screen

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, display

In Debian 9, my KDE desktop is somehow broken. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it with no luck.

This did happen a little bit after I installed `i3`, but I have no idea if that has anything to do with it.

KDM loads just fine, I can log in, but KDE loads to a blank screen and a cursor: no panel and no desktop background. I would do a screen shot, but it would literally be a screen shot of a blank screen. I can open a terminal with `Ctrl Alt T` and open any apps from the terminal, but KDE itself doesn't load up. Here is the output of `kstart plasmashell`

```
kstart(1648) main: Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended 

kstart(1648) Bridge::setRootObject: "KAccessibleBridge: setRootObject object=" "kstart (QApplication)" 

kstart(1648) Bridge::setRootObject: KAccessibleBridge: Starting kaccessibleapp dbus service 

kstart(1648) Bridge::Private::app: Connected with the org.kde.kaccessibleapp dbus-service 

kstart(1648) Bridge::notifyAccessibilityUpdate: "ObjectDestroyed" "object=" " (QWidget)" "name=" ""
```

Comment: this kind of profound instability is why I finally after a decade gave up on KDE.

Comment: Well, I gave up. Completely uninstalled KDE and SDDM. Installed Cinnamon and Light DM. Light DM is not working, but I get to show the kids how to log in with startx in the morning. Debian seems to handle that better than any other distro that I've tried it with. I'll try to get Light DM going tomorrow, but I think we can handle the TTY/startx thing just fine.

Comment: You can use nodm for login free start if I remember right. When I got hit on all my systems with catastrophic KDE failures I fought it for a week and finally gave up and  moved to XFCE + lightdm, and it's been smooth pleasant sailing ever since. It was a big red warning flag when KDE moved from kdm to the buggy sddm, which is not in the project, or wasn't. The kde devs ignoring bug reports about these instability issues was the second red flag in my case, and 2 red flags is all I need.

Comment: KDE plasma is very stable for me. Did you try deleting/moving config files, e.g. `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`? There are a few others, too. Did KDE plasma ever work for you? What happened just before it broke?